# Image of $A^\frac{1}{2}$ equal to image of $A$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A\in B(H)$ be a **closed range** positive operator, and $A^\frac{1}{2}$ its square root. Clearly image of $A$ is a subset of image of $A^\frac{1}{2}~~$($R(A)\subset R(A^\frac{1}{2})$). How do we prove $R(A)= R(A^\frac{1}{2})$? 
I edite the question

Comment: Is $A$ compact?

Comment: @Kevin, No. Just a positive self adjoint operator

Comment: Ok, is $H$ a Hilbert space?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, $H$ is a Hilbert space, and $B(H)$ means the space of bounded linear operators.

Comment: @Kevin how can one define "self-adjoint operator" in a non-Hilbert space?

Comment: @surb Just wanted clarification as it was not defined in OP

Comment: @Kevin too bad :), I would have loved to see such a definition. Would be interesting

Comment: @Surb I know of a definition of self adjointedness on a real Banach space if this is interesting to you?

Comment: @Kevin yes, I'd be very interested by that. Does it goes along the lines of : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154474/self-adjointness-for-banach-spaces ?

Comment: @surb Yes, the Wójcik, paper came to mind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. Set $H = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and let $A$ be the multiplication operator defined by

$$ A \left( (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \right) = \left( \frac{x_n}{n} \right)_{n=1}^{\infty}. $$

Then

$$ A^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \right) = \left( \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}} \right)_{n=1}^{\infty} $$

and $\left( \frac{1}{n^{1.5}} \right)_{n=1}^{\infty} \in R(A^{\frac{1}{2}})$ but not in $R(A)$.

---

If the range of $A$ is closed then the result is true. To see why, note that if $x \in \ker(A^{\frac{1}{2}})$ then $Ax = A^{\frac{1}{2}} A^{\frac{1}{2}} x = 0$ so $x \in \ker(A)$ while if $x \in \ker(A)$ then
$$ \left< A^{\frac{1}{2}}x, A^{\frac{1}{2}}x \right> = \left< x, Ax \right> = 0 $$

so $x \in \ker(A^{\frac{1}{2}})$. Now,

$$ R(A) \subseteq R \left(A^{\frac{1}{2}} \right) \subseteq \overline{ R \left( A^{\frac{1}{2}} \right)} = \ker \left( A^{\frac{1}{2}} \right)^{\perp} = \ker(A)^{\perp} = \overline{R(A)} = R(A) $$

and so we get $R(A) = R \left(A^{\frac{1}{2}} \right)$.

Comment: BTW, in general you can often find counterexamples easily by playing with multiplication operators. This is not really restrictive as the spectral theorem tells you any self adjoint operator is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator.

Comment: Does the equation prove If $A$ is closed range?

Comment: @niki: I've added the argument in the case $A$ has closed range.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.